# Почему Canvas изменяет позицию и размер элементов?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: Окно приложения]

На верхней картинке макет приложения. На нижней запущенное приложение.
Видно, что происходит смещение кнопок вниз и уменьшение размера формы. Для позиционирования использован контейнер Canvas.

Обычно используют другие контейнеры (делят окно Grid). Но это тестовый пример. И, как видно, Canvas работает не корректно - то есть не выполняет свое назначение - жесткое (абсолютное) позиционирование элементов. Причина изменения размеров окна тоже не ясна (ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="450" Width="800")

Код разметки XAML

```
<Window x:Class="action_programm.ProgramWindow" Loaded="ProgramWindow_Loaded"
    
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"       
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="ProgramWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    
   TextElement.Foreground="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignBody}"
    TextElement.FontWeight="Regular"
    TextElement.FontSize="13"
    TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal"
    TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Auto"
    Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
    FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignFont}"
            
    
   >
<Grid>


    <Canvas Background="Green" Height="420" Width="790">
        
        <Label Content="Список действий" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10"/>

        <ListBox Name="ActionListBox" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="40" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#616161" Background="#424242"  Height="330" Width="774">
        <ListBoxItem  Content="Сообщение"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Пункт 2"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="Новая команда"/>
        </ListBox>
    
    

    <Button Name="UpButton" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Bottom="10" Click="UpButton_Click" Content="Вверх" Width="80" FontSize="13"/>
        <Button Name="DownButton" Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Bottom="10" Click="DownButton_Click" Content="Вниз"  Width="80" FontSize="13"/>
        <Button Name="AddButton" Canvas.Left="190" Canvas.Bottom="10" Click="AddButton_Click" Content="Добавить"  Width="100" FontSize="13"/>
        <Button Name="DeleteButton" Canvas.Left="300" Canvas.Bottom="10" Click="DeleteButton_Click" Content="Удалить"  Width="100" FontSize="13"/>
        <Button Name="SaveProjectButton" Canvas.Left="410" Canvas.Bottom="10" Click="SaveProjectButton_Click" Content="Сохранить проект"  Width="182" FontSize="13"/>
        <Button Name="SaveProjectAsButton" Canvas.Left="602" Canvas.Bottom="10" Click="SaveProjectAsButton_Click" Content="Сохранить проект как..."  Width="182" FontSize="13"/>



    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

Почему Canvas изменяет позицию и размер элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окно состоит из нескольких частей и включает рамки, системные элементы и саму клиентскую область для отображения различных элементов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Размер указывается для всего окна и при этом клиентская область гораздо меньше по причинам как раз таки остальных элементов.

```
String clientSize = 
    ((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualWidth.ToString() + "x" + 
    ((FrameworkElement)this.Content).ActualHeight.ToString();
```

Можно поставить вместо размеров окна `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` и тогда окно само подтсроится под контент, только тогда размеры надо указать у самого Grid. Или же убрать Grid оставив сразу корневой элемент Canvas.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow" 
        ....
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
        <Canvas Background="Green" Height="420" Width="790">
            ...
        </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало как надо. 

Смущает то, что Visual Studio "обманывает" меня, показывая картинку в дизайнере, которой при запуске может и не быть (как у меня - в дизайнере всё выглядит хорошо, а при запуске всё сместилось). 

Про размер окна понял. Ещё хочу спросить - стоит ли рассматривать окно как "обертку" контента? Размер контента указывать атрибутами контейнера, а окно всегда задавать SizeToContent? Пусть оно всегда "оборачивает" контейнер.

Наверно Title и Border может быть разным, в зависимости от настроек/темы ОС (не знаю как это влияет и какой там расчет).

Comment: @Иван, обычно контент принято делать динамическим и не задавать принудительно размеры в единицах, разве что min и max. Поэтому в вашем случае это скорее исключение, чем правило. Но если вы все-таки делаете фиксированное окно, то вполне рабочий вариант, так как остальные элементы действительно зависят от настроек системы..